# How to send c# objects with method implementation over the network

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, protocol-buffers, grpc

First of all, the requirement : I need to send .net objects over the network. Here is a basic structure of the class -

```
class something : somethingelse
{
    public int count { get; set; }

    public List<object> items { get; set; }

    public something(string name)
    {
        //some initialization
    }

    public object Evaluate(string type)
    {
        //some logic
    }
}
```

The `something` class have many different implementation on the server, all derived from an Interface (hence, they have same structure). However, in each of them, the logic inside the `Evaluate` method changes. Client application have no idea about the implementations beforehand. What we need is that server will send an object to the client, based on an identifier in the client request, and client will use that object to evaluate the data further.

**What I already tried:**

1. Basic .net serialization : It seems they do serialize only the state of the object (data members), not the actual object. To use the methods, I need to have the DLL referenced at the client-side. But as I mentioned, client should have no idea about the implementations beforehand.
2. .NET remoting : I believe this has become an obsolete tech. I would not prefer to build a whole new app based on it.
3. WCF : I could not find if it fits in, for the same reason as #1
4. gRPC with Protocol Buffer : I did look into it specifically because it seems to be faster (and we have plans to create large objects). However, I could not figure out a similar way to serialize a whole object, instead of only data members.

Any help any any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All of these send the *data* for objects. That's what serialization is about. If you want to send the *behavior* you'll need the client to have the code. You could send the client the assembly as well... or let the client send RPCs to the server to execute operations and return results.

Comment: @JonSkeet : What should be the possible way to send the assembly as well? And also any specific RPC library, from performance point of view?

Comment: @atanu that would be **absurdly** dangerous; please please don't seriously consider this. In addition to the obvious security issues, it will also be incredibly brittle re versioning, but that's a minor point in comparison. It is also technically challenging because you need to send the assembly plus dependencies, then run them in an isolate app-domain or process so that competing dependencies don't fight. Nobody supports that - because it is a horrible horrible idea.

Comment: @MarcGravell : So, its RPC finally. Any recommendations?

Comment: It's hard to make recommendations without knowing more about what you're trying to achieve. I have a natural bias towards gRPC as that's what I know best. (And despite my earlier comment, I completely agree with Marc about the dangers and difficulties of sending the code along with the object - I should have added my concerns in my first comment.)

Comment: Thank you guys. You saved a lot of my time of R&D. Now I can focus on RPC itself. :)